# Empty file when uploading rar VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have upload function in vuejs but when I'm trying to upload file with .rar file type there is no return in console.log it becomes empty.

Below is my current code

```
//Input
    <input hidden type="file" accept="" class="" @change="changeFiles1" ref="report_file_1"/>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-custom btn-green btn-small" @click="$refs.report_file_1.click()" :disabled="document_type_1 == ''">+ Add Files</button><br>
    enter code here
    // Here is my Method 
    changeFiles1(){
           console.log(this.$refs.report_file_1.files)
    }
```

When I upload file thats not RAR it returns like this.
[image]

but when I upload RAR it doesn't return anything
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should compose your uploader component like this - then it will work even with RAR files:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="drop_area"
    :class="{ draghover: drag_over }"
    @dragover.prevent="drag_over = true"
    @dragenter.prevent="drag_over = true"
    @dragleave.prevent="drag_over = false"
    @dragend.prevent="drag_over = false"
    @drop.prevent="chooseFile"
  >
    <svg width="34" height="30" viewBox="0 0 34 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        fill="currentColor"
        d="M2.83333 6.50004H0V13.5834H0.0141667L0 26.3334C0 27.8917 1.275 29.1667 2.83333 29.1667H28.3333V26.3334H2.83333V6.50004ZM31.1667 3.66671H19.8333L17
        0.833374H8.5C6.94167 0.833374 5.68083 2.10837 5.68083 3.66671L5.66667 20.6667C5.66667 22.225 6.94167 23.5 8.5 23.5H31.1667C32.725 23.5 34 22.225 34
        20.6667V6.50004C34 4.94171 32.725 3.66671 31.1667 3.66671ZM9.91667 19.25L16.2917 10.75L21.25 17.1392L24.7917 12.875L29.75 19.25H9.91667Z"
      />
    </svg>
    <div class="pt-4">Drag files here to upload</div>
    <div class="py-3">OR</div>
    <v-btn ref="file_btn" tag="label" :for="'filebox_' + _uid" :tabindex="tab" class="pointer" color="primary" text @click="selectFile">
      Browse files
    </v-btn>
    <input :id="'filebox_' + _uid" ref="file_ctrl" type="file" :accept="accept" :multiple="multiple" @change="chooseFile">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DropZone',
  props:
  {
    /**
     * Desired tab-index - handy if you include the component into a larger form and want proper keyboard navigation
     */
    tab:
    {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    /**
     * Allow selecting more than 1 file at once
     */
    multiple:
    {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    /**
     * Allowed MIME types for the files
     */
    accept:
    {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  data()
  {
    return {
      drag_over: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectFile()
    {
      this.$refs.file_btn.focus();
      this.$refs.file_btn.click();
    },
    chooseFile(event)
    {
      this.drag_over = false;
      /**
       * Emitted when new file(s) has been selected
       * @event change
       * @property {object} FileList
       */
      const files = (event.dataTransfer || event.target).files;
      if (files.length > 100) alert('Too many files - more than 100!');
      else this.$emit('change', files);
      clearFileInput(this.$refs.file_ctrl);
    },
  },
};

/**
 * Clears the file control to allow selecting new files
 */
function clearFileInput(ctrl)
{
  try
  {
    ctrl.value = null;
  }
  catch (ex)
  {}
  if (ctrl.value) ctrl.parentNode.replaceChild(ctrl.cloneNode(true), ctrl);
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.drop_area
{
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 28px 12px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.drop_area svg
{
  color: grey;
}

.drop_area input[type='file']
{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.draghover
{
  border-color: black;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
</style>
```